# Pass a session cookie to another ip?

Tags: javascript, http, session, node.js, couchdb

Is it possible to get a session from a server and pass that session cookie to another ip so that one can use it to communicate with the server that issued that session?

```
session server -> my backend server 1: getting session cookie
my backend server 1 -> my backend server 2: passing session cookie
session server <-> my backend server 2: communicating directly with session server without the middle man.
```

I'm using CouchDB and Node.js/Javascript.

I tried to send the set-cookie header received from session server (couchdb) to backend server 2 and it did set the session cookie in the browser. But when making requests to couchdb it didn't send that cookie along. I think it's because of it has to be the same ip that it got the session from, in this case, the server 1.

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies are based on domains, so the browser will only send the cookie back to the domain it was set on.

You get the client to send a request to the second server with data allowing the server to create a new cookie. Not sure what kind of security you need.

Comment: Im actually interested in setting a .domain.com (wildcard)

Do you know if this is possible?